# Wordpress next post link, not working as expected

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to exclude categories from a Wordpress next post link, and it still shows the category when clicked.

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', ' ', TRUE, '1' and '2' and '3' and '8' and '9'); ?>
```

From here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress 3.3 `AND` was deprecated. the correct way of doing this now is either putting them in an array or separating them with a comma.

in your case:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', ' ', TRUE, '1, 2, 3, 8, 9'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', ' ', TRUE, array(1, 2, 3, 8, 9)); ?>
```

Comment: Still not working for me! Seems to just ignore the 'TRUE' and array in all ways of writing it...